# Find specific word in text file

Tags: php, regex

Think I have a text file with the following:

```
Hello my name is Jack Jordon. What is your name? Let there be a party. Is your name Jack Marais, I didn't think so Jack van Riebeeck. Good day Jack.
```

How can I find all the "Jack" words and the word after it with PHP?

So the results would be

```
Jack Jordon
Jack Marais
Jack van
Jack
```

Is it possible to do this with regex or is there a better way?

Comment: `van Riebeeck` is two words.

Comment: First you should think about, what you're accepting as a name, and specify if you know the name you're searching for. For example if you got a "Jack Van der Buren et Grumpli" or the expression Candle Jack, do you need those names too? There's alot you can do with regex, but first you should outline those requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
'/\bJack\s+(?:\s+\w+|$)/'
```

This regex will only find a single word after `Jack` OR end of line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~\bJack(?>\s+[a-z]+)?~i', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: This works well. I have tested it [here](http://goo.gl/Hoz8Sj)

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$input  = 'Hello my name is Jack Jordon. What is your name? Let there be a party. Is your name Jack Marais, I didn\'t think so Jack van Riebeeck. Good day Jack.';
$search = 'Jack';

preg_match_all('/(' . $search . '[a-z ]*[A-Z][a-z]+)/', $input, $matches);
$output = $matches[0];
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$yourSentend = "Hello my name is Jack Jordon. What is your name? Let there be a party. Is your name Jack Marais, I didn't think so Jack van Riebeeck. Good day Jack.";
$words = explode(' ', $yourSentence);
for ($i = 0, $m = count($words); $i < $m; $i++) {
    if ($words[$i] == 'Jack') {
        echo $words[$i].' '.$words[$i+1];
    }
}
```

This will echo each Jack + the next word.

Comment: `$string = "Hello Jack, I am me"`, after your explode, you will not match this `Jack`, as it is `Jack,`

Comment: It won't get Jack. - with dot

Comment: But how with a text file?

Comment: Just read the content of the file then put it in $yourSentence. You can too clean to remove the ',', etc.